# A question about residual stress

Tags: material-science, metals

[Shot peening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_peening) is a process of inducing [*residual compressive stress*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_stress) on the surface layer of metal parts. When shooting particles are colliding on the surface of metal there is a compressive stress. My question is, how can resultant compressive stress exists after the force causing the compression is removed (i.e. after the shooting particle leaves the surface)?

Normally we need a force to hold the object in compressive state. For residual stress, are there any parts in tension to balance this stress?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the wiki page pointed to in your question states early on that, indeed, tensile stresses exist in the material as well as compressive stresses. The plastic deformation induced by shot peening results in compression at the surface (where it dramatically extends fatigue life) at the cost of tensile stresses below the surface.  Since cracks are most likely to occur on the surface, keeping it under compression is a good thing. Most introductory metallurgy or mechanical properties texts will cover this (and many other processing methods).

Edit (additional info): Focusing on fatigue, cyclic loading of a part will lead to cyclic compression/tension, particularly at surfaces where these forces will be maximum under, e.g. bending loads on beams. If a crack is present, the crack tip will act as a stress concentrator, and the crack tip can propagate.  After lots (10's of thousands) of flexes, the crack will finally take off, resulting in failure of the mechanical device.  Residual compressive stresses basically mean that the crack will remain closed until an even larger external tensile force is applies. This means that for sufficiently small loading of a pre-stressed member, fatigue failure is effectively eliminated. Note also that (initially) small surface cracks are a primary cause of brittle failure (glasses, ceramics) as well.  For example. Pyrex is a glass treated with ion exchange to create a surface compressive layer, effectively increasing the shock needed to break the glass (so you can drop it off the counter at have it survive).

Compressive stress is initially hard to visualize.  Often we are held back by our 'experience' considering 'ideal' materials.  Most actual engineering materials are far from ideal - they are polycrystalline, multi component materials that have been heated, beated, and treated leaving a decidedly non-uniform stress field inside the material. So, where is the compressive stress hiding?  Dislocation loops and tangles; grain boundaries (think of stresses at plate edges in plate tectonics), triple junctions of grains, second phase precipitates - all can respond to shock processes such as peening, and then not be able to snap back.  Instead of wondering how stresses can remain in the material, the harder thing to visualize is how to get a stress-free material.

Comment: Fracture is usually initiated at a point of _stress concentration_ - a surface crack. If the crack starts out in compression, additional tension is needed before the crack can propagate. Probably worth expanding your answer along those lines - you have most of the information there but a bit more would make this an even better answer.

Comment: @Jon Custer : The surface is plastically deformed, but does plastic deformation necessarily implies the presence of residual stress?

How can a tensile stress built up inside the metal? It is hard to visualize.

Answer (score 0):

Residual stress resulting from peeing have a typical shape. this shape can be defined in 3 points. the first point at the surface is defined as Sigma_srs which is in compression, the residual stress decreases to reach it compressive peak Sigma_mcrs at a Zm depth. Finally, the residual stress increases and become goes into tension at Z0. 
To define your peening process it is important to know your max compressive stress Sigma_mcrs and the compressive layer defined by z0. residual stress measurement can be easily performed with XRD http://www.veqter.co.uk/residual-stress-measurement/x-ray-diffraction Or Incremental Centre-Hole Drilling http://www.veqter.co.uk/residual-stress-measurement/centre-hole-drilling.